# Compare two files and print the differences in specific format not using "diff" command

Tags: awk, sed, diff

hi I have two files each containing 1 row of data each .. Usually I just use diff command to see what is the difference between the two files.

```
 file1:
    a.tag
    b.tag
    c.tag

 file2:
   a.tag
   b.tag
   d.tag
```

I want a command that just shows me what is difference is the file and also gives me the file names in this format.  I use diff but if just does not do what I want ..   I want the out put to look like this  ..

what I like to do: compare the two files and print only what is different in each file in this format:

```
 file1:c.tag
 file2:d.tag
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the `diff` command provides quite flexible output options. You can use this command:

```
diff 
  --unchanged-line-format='' \
  --old-line-format='file1:%L' \
  --new-line-format='file2:%L' \
  file1 file2
```

Output:

```
file1:c.tag
file2:d.tag
```

I'm using the `%L` escape sequence for both old and new lines. `%L` means print the contents of the line. Unchanged lines will get skipped since I pass an empty string for that.

---

To generalize that and make it work with arbitrary file names, you can wrap it into a shell function. Put this into your bashrc for example:

```
function mydiff() {
    diff 
      --unchanged-line-format='' \
      --old-line-format="$1:%L" \
      --new-line-format="$2:%L" \
      "$1" "$2"
}
```

Source the bashrc or start a new shell and call it like this:

```
mydiff file1 file2
```

Comment: Hi I tried the command but it is not working - I put everything on one line and i get this

Comment: Simple and elegant solution! Some explanation of these options would be even more helpful

Comment: yes there are two files as I have listed them file1 and file2  .. i get the following when I run ur command diff: extra operand ` file1'
diff: Try `diff --help' for more information.

Comment: @theuniverseisflat Have you removed the slashes? They are just needed for the multiline version. Otherwise, which version of diff are you using? (diff --version)

Comment: hi I'am using  diff (GNU diffutils) 2.8.1

Comment: I'm using GNU diff 3.3. Can you try a recent version? (Try use diff3 if your distro ships with that)

Comment: can u let me knwo what last comamnd file{1,2} does?

Comment: It's a bash feature called [*brace expansion*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html).

Comment: thx .. but if I have different file name otejhr than file1 and file2 how do I use this?

Comment: Simply pass them one after one. I'll remove the brace expansion from the answer. It does just help in the theoretical case that you have file[1,2]..

Comment: my file names are different each time

Comment: diff --unchanged-line-format='' --old-line-format='file1:%L'  --new-line-format='file2:%L'  file before after'  tries this not working